# the thinking behind ADA boosting

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, generalized-additive-model

I'm looking at the following derivation of ADA boosting. 
http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/inst/ag-ki/adaboost4.pdf

Now whenever i've read about ADA boosting one of the unique properties of the model is described as the fact that misclassified points in weaker models are given a higher weighting, almost as if this is the motivation behind the algorithm.

However in the derivation and in others i've seen it seems to be almost a convenient consequence, even though it is still mentioned as the idea behind the model. I'm particularly refering to the weight $w_{i}^{(m)}$ provided in equation (2) in the paper. Of course we'll probably never know the process behind the derivation exactly. But does anyone know if it's more of a direct consequence? Or whether it was the initial idea and the mathematics was developed to make it look easy?